# Rally App SDK 2.0: Cannot load Rally.ui.cardboard.ArtifactCard when referencing /apps/2.0p3/sdk.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

This item fails to load because of its dependency on the Ext.Loader: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/panel/Rally/ui/cardboard/ArtifactCard.js?_dc=1343151803942

I have used

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
```

to remedy this issue. However, ArtifactCard.js is still unable to be loaded. Any insight into why this is? Should the preview 3 script not be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the ArtifactCard class has been removed in favor of just using the Rally.ui.cardboard.Card class. The 2.0p3 API docs can be found here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.Card

Comment: Ah. Well, after having done a little modification to resolve that dependency, it seems that a lot of my controls are broken in this new preview.. I am trying to move from the first preview. Is it worth looking into, or should I stick to what works until there is a more official release?

Comment: Rally.ui.cardboard.Card is probably mostly stable at this point.  We just got done doing a major refactor to address some performance issues with the board which involved converting from a series of nested containers cards being a component built up using templates.

Answer (score 1):

The second preview is only one that is currently static. At this point preview 3 is best though of as a canary or constantly changing version.

There are some things that will work different in the next preview not the least of the upgrade to Ext 4.1

Comment: Alright. I think I will stick with the first preview until the next stable preview is available, if there are going to be even more changes from now until then. Thanks!

Comment: We have released 2.0p2 and it is stable you can find it here.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/doc/

Comment: Hmm.. Ok. I just made the reference change, and it seems to work fine with the defined controls, unlike preview 3, so I guess I will stick with this for now. Thanks.